# how can i use same image for different screen size in android?

Tags: android, image, image-resizing

I have an app which i want to show an image inside the image view inside an activity.
I use a 160 dip for image height and I want to image fit across device screen .
I can use "xxxhdpi" , "xxhpi" ,  for different screen size but this make my application size very big.  I want to support screen size like 1440*2560 
with 480 dip. i should use an image size like 1440*640 and put in "xxxhdpi" drawable folder .

Comment: Take a look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: make folders for different resolutions like hdpi ,xhdp,xxhdpi or etc.then design  for every layout for respect to folder resolution

Comment: 9-patch images may useful

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:
      use this https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html   link and generator image for multiple screen

Comment: the problem is i want use for example 10 images and if i want to use nine-patch or something like that my app size would be very big i want and alternative solution.

Comment: other wise you should fix height and width of your imageview depending on your screen size but not sure how much it will be usefull@SeyedMassoudMotallebi

Answer (score 0):

You can put a version of your image that is big enough and fitXY it in your ImageView. This way it stretches to the ImageView size.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are simple icons you can consider using SVG images. You can convert svg images into android xml code using this link [enter link description here](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/)

This way you don't have to be worry about the resolution of device.

Comment: i used a graphic image not a simple icon i have an image view and i have lets say 10 different landscape image and after every 10 second this image will be changed.